# Create calculated column from a different table

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I have a date dimension table and a table that contains the latest date available (only 1 row). There is no relationship between these 2 tables. I'm trying to create a calculated column in Date dimension using this (getting the monthend date of latest previous month and flagging Y or N):

```
_Flag := IF('Datex'[Date] <=  EOMONTH('Latest Datex'[Latest Date], -1), "Y", "N")
```

I'm having an error using above. How do I write it?

Answer (score 0):

**Use New Measure:**

`_Flag = IF(MAX('Datex'[Date]) <=  EOMONTH(MAX('Latest Datex'[Latest Date]), -1), "Y", "N")`